# Spring Cloud Stream Manual Poller Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I don't want to use @KafkaListener or @StreamListener but I want to manually poll kafka. I am using spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka library and I have the following Kafka Producer

```
  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template;

  public void sendMessages() {
    IntStream.range(2)
             .forEach(val -> {
               template.send("kafka-topic", "hello".getBytes());
             });
  }
```

I would like to manually poll the same kafka topic using spring-kafka. I tried the following consumer

```
 @Autowired
  private ConsumerFactory consumerFactory;

  public void processKafkaRecords() throws InterruptedException {
    Consumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer("0", "consumer-1");
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("kafka-topic"));
    ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> poll = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
    poll.forEach(record -> {
      log.info("record {}", record);
    });
  }
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pollableInput.destination=kafka-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pollableInput.group=kafka-topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pollableInput.consumer.batch-mode=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pollableInput.consumer.header-mode=none
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pollableInput.consumer.use-native-decoding=true

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.pollableInput.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false
```

However, the consumer never gets any records which the producer had sent. Any ideas how to manually poll a kafka topic?

Comment: You need to show your consumer factory configuration and application.yml/properties.

Comment: How do you trigger the consumer? And why are you using steam and then post using a normal product and poll by consumer?

Comment: @GaryRussell I don't have consumer factory configuration, I assume it will use the default one, I simply bind it to the kafka topic, is this not enough? is there a simple example where I can see a simple setup? thank you

Comment: @daniu the consumer is a spring bean, I trigger it manually. I use spring stream because I ve been using streamListener but now I want to start polling manually

Comment: Well, you are getting a consumer factory from somewhere; otherwise the `@Autowired` wouldn't work. If your Kafka is on localhost; you are probably getting Boot's default. You need to add `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest` - see the Spring Boot Kafka documentation chapter for more information. You also need to wait for your subscription to occur via a `RebalanceListener` (or use `consumer.assign()` instead of `subscribe()`).

Comment: @GaryRussell is there a complete example config somewhere? thanks

Comment: There are several samples in the spring-kafka project as well as many test cases in the project itself; most of those tests that use `Consumer`s directly use utility methods in `KafkaTestutils`; I can put something together tomorrow but the bottom line is, when you use `subscribe()`, a single `poll()` call is often not enough - you need to keep polling until the partitions are assigned. A `RebalanceListener` will help to determine when that happens.

Comment: @GaryRussell there is no consumer.assign() method, the signature expects the topic and the partition in the format. for example consumer.assign(Collections.singleton(new TopicPartition("kafka-topic", 0))). This seems to poll some of the results but not all so maybe I should use RebalanceListener as you suggested. Do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply there is a no-argument version of `assign`, just that using `assign(...)` avoids the need to wait for the subscription to be assigned partitions; but you have to assign all the partitions. See `EmbeddedKafkaBroker.consumeFromEmbeddedTopics(...)` for an example that uses a rebalance listener to wait for the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons:

1. `Duration.ofMillis(1000)` - Try increasing the time, 1s might be too low in some cases unless both your client and kafka are running on the same machine. Because the documentation of `poll(Duration)` says ***If the timeout expires, an empty record set will be returned***
2. If you have started the producer first and then the consumer and you did not set the offset reset strategy to earliest then you cannot see any messages because the consumer will be consuming from the latest offset by default. So, try setting the following `auto.offset.reset=earliest`
3. Another consumer from the same consumer group might be running and that there is only 1 partition or the consumer group is already at the last offset. In this case, you can try changing the consumer group id.

Comment: duration didn't make any difference neither the prop reset=earliest. I tried doing consumer.assign(Collections.singleton(new TopicPartition("kafka-topic", 0))) instead of subscribe and this started polling some of the results instantly but not all. I feel I have to implement RebalanceListener as suggested above.

Comment: If you want to poll from the beginning of the topic, then you need to call `seekToBeginning()` method. As for subscription, if the consumer group offsets are pointing to the last offsets then you cannot see any messages. Try changing the `group.id` or resetting the consumer group